# Which gives me better performance Activerecord find_by or where?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Suppose i have model(Account) with following columns account_id, user_id, party_id, date and name

and i execute:

```
Account.find_by_account_id_and_user_id_and_party_id_and_date_and_name(1,2,3,"2012-03-12","Venus")
```

and

```
   Account.where(:account_id => 1, :user_id => 2, :party_id => 3,:date => "2012-03-28",:name => "Venus").limit(1).first
```

Which will give me better performance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`where` gives you marginally better performance. `find_by` is implemented through `method_missing` magic; `method_missing` requires a call to the object's method table to see if there's an existing method first, and if not then a call to `method_missing`, whereas `where` just finds the method correctly.

To see actual benchmarks of this, [check out this post](http://www.alef1.org/ruby/method_missing/).

Comment: Thanks Veraticus. i was not knowing about this method_missing concept with find_by.  I knew that both ways fore same query and using where is a cleaner way of writing that big query

Answer (score 1):

The database query they output will be the same in both examples. So, in terms of that sort of performance, they are equal. However, the former will require a method_missing lookup and dynamic method definition the first time you use it and, to me, is much harder to read and is not really a great way too approach a query with that many parameters.

I'd go with the 'where' based solely on readability personally, but they'll both output the same select query so it really won't matter much anyways.